# Higher Order Functions

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions

I am trying to learn about higher order functions from this guide here http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions. But I am sort of confused and hoped that someone can clarify some things for me.

So I am looking at this example:

```
applyTwice :: (a -> a) -> a -> a  
applyTwice f x = f (f x)
```

Ok so `applyTwice` is a function that takes two arguments, a function which takes a type `a` and return type `a`, the second argument is a type `a`. And the function returns a type `a`.

And in the command line we get this result:

```
ghci> applyTwice (++ " HAHA") "HEY"  
"HEY HAHA HAHA"
```

So the function `f` is `(++)` and its type is `[a] -> [a] -> [a]`. `(++ " HAHA")` is a partial application correct? We have only given it one parameter and so it returns `[a] -> [a]`. 
In the `applyTwice` defintion, I want to start with the `(f x)` part. So f takes "HEY" this produces "HEY HAHA" which is type `a`, and then I need to apply `f` to get "HEY HAHA HAHA"

edit:
With these two examples: what is the difference between `(++ " HAHA")` and `("HAHA " ++)`

```
ghci> applyTwice (++ " HAHA") "HEY"  
"HEY HAHA HAHA"  

ghci> applyTwice ("HAHA " ++) "HEY"  
"HAHA HAHA HEY"
```

Comment: It sounds like you've got the basic gist of it. Do you have a specific question?

Comment: `(++ " HAHA")` is actually a [section](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-300003.5) but beyond that your understanding look correct. What do you have a problem with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is the difference between `(++ " HAHA")` and `("HAHA " ++)`?

`(++ " HAHA")` gives `" HAHA"` as the second argument to the `(++)` function.

`("HAHA " ++)` gives `"HAHA "` as the first argument to the `(++)` function.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between `(++ " HAHA")` and `("HAHA " ++)` has to do with the order in which parameters are passed in. If we explicitly use lambdas, the expressions look like this:

```haskell
(++ " HAHA") == (\x -> x ++ " HAHA") -- expands to: "HEY" ++ " HAHA"
("HAHA " ++) == (\x -> "HAHA " ++ x) -- expands to: "HAHA " ++ "HEY"
```

Answer (score 3):

`(++ "HAHA")` is the same as `(\x -> x ++ "HAHA")`

whereas

`("HAHA" ++)` equals `(\x -> "HAHA" ++ x)`

This is also quite obvious from your tests. This syntax is called *section* and makes partial application of (non-commutative) binary operators easier and more intuitive.